# question about shift operation and bracket operation

Tags: c

```
for(i=0; i<8 ;i++)
{
    SRCLK = 0;
    SER = (sendData>>7);
    sendData <<= 1;
    SRCLK = 1;
}
```

and

```
for(i=0; i<8 ;i++)
{
    SRCLK = 0;
    SER = (sendData>>(7-i));
    SRCLK = 1;
}
```

i think there is no difference bettween them. i builded the code and download to my 51MCU. i use **SER** to send serial data to 74HC595, these codes displayed different phenomenon. thank for your explanation of this question.

Comment: You probably meant to do `SER = (sendData>>(7u-i)) & 1u;`? That is, grab 1 bit at a time.

Comment: How is `SER` defined? You second case `sendData>>(7-i)` might be interpreted as a boolean, giving "1" whenever the expression is not zero.

Comment: Yes, I see the code meaning. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `sendData` is an 8-bit `unsigned char` the first version of the code will send the binary bits one by one, starting with the most significant one. It does this by clearing the bits from the highest down at each step before shifting the next one to the lowest position.

```
    unsigned char sendData = 0xB0; // 0b11000000

                            // i = 0
    SER = (sendData >> 7);  // SER      = 0x01
    sendData <<= 1;         // sendData = 0x80

                            // i = 1
    SER = (sendData >> 7);  // SER      = 0x01
    sendData <<= 1;         // sendData = 0x00

                            // i = 2...7
    SER = (sendData >> 7);  // SER      = 0x00
    sendData <<= 1;         // sendData = 0x00
```

The second version does no such clearing and just shifts the same bits each time.

```
                            // i = 0
    SER = (sendData >> 7);  // SER      = 0x01

                            // i = 1
    SER = (sendData >> 6);  // SER      = 0x03

                            // i = 2
    SER = (sendData >> 5);  // SER      = 0x06
```

---

[ *EDIT* ] To address the points made in comments, the first version of the code always has the leftmost 7 bits set to `0` in `SER`. It's only the rightmost (least significant) bit which can be `0` or `1`.

This is because at the `i`'th step the leftmost `i` bits of `sendData` are `0` after `i` repeats of the left `<<` shift. Then right `>>` shifting `sendData` by `i-1` discards the rightmost `i-1` bits. So in the end the `8-i`'th  bit of `sendData` gets placed into the least significant bit of `SER`, and all other `SER` bits are set to `0`.

As noted by @ChrisDodd, the second version of the code could be corrected to achieve the same result by replacing `SER = (sendData>>(7-i))` with `SER = (sendData>>(7-i)) & 1`.

Comment: You can make the second version equivalent to the first by changing it to `SER = (sendData>>(7-i)) & 1;`

Comment: first, thank you very much. But there is another question that **SER** can just get one bit at every Rising edge of SRCLK. so i think the code
'SER = sendData'
just send the last bit to SER whatever sendData high bit is. Because 'SER' is just one-bit data, it can only get one-bit data, even 8-bit data give to it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Right, thanks for making that point. I edited the answer to (try and) elaborate it.

Comment: @liaohuguang Please see the clarification at the end of the answer. The last bit is the same in both versions of the code. If you see a difference in behavior then higher bits must also matter in some way.

Answer (score 0):

first, thank the guys @ChrisDodd and @dixv for help.
actually, `SER` represent the pin3.4 of 51MCU, so it can just recieve `bool` data `0` or `1`.so the code `SER = sendData;` is NOT to give the last bit to `SER` but to run follow mission:

1. judge `sendData` equal `0` or not
2. sendData equal `0`, then give false `0` to `SER`. in contrast, `1` to `SER`

eg: if `LED` means pin0.0 of 51MCU

`LED = 0x0a;`//0x08 = 0000 1010, the last bit is 0, but LED = 1

Comment: These clarifications would be better [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62125914/edit) in the question itself than a separate post,

Comment: `sendData equal 0 or not` With the example used in my answer, both `sendData` and `SER` are `==0` in the last `6` steps of the loop when using the first version of the code, but `!=0` with the second version.

Comment: thanks for your advising, i will pay attention next time. my problem has sovled with your help. Again, thank you very much.